# Is there a better way to collect and join values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

When I collect values from an array, I like using this ruby idiom:

```
users.collect &:email
```

But then when I want to join those values, I end up having to expand it like so:

```
users.collect { |user| user.email }.join(", ")
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why you have to expand it. You can do this:

```
users.collect(&:email).join(', ')


# or you can use collect's alias, map, 
# which is a much better name for this operation :)
users.map(&:email).join(', ')
```

The `&` operator in this context is a [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html). It basically treats the symbol you supply as a method name that it should call on a receiver and return its result.

Comment: I don't think he knows about the `&:` operator, perhaps it would be also be appropriate to explain what it does, since it's not always very obvious :) Good answer, though. Quite nearly put it as I would've.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it hadn't occurred to me that I could put a `&:` operator in parentheses.

Comment: It just occurred to me now, that even though I usually don't put parentheses around argument lists, I have never ever used a `&:` without them. I don't know why. Maybe it's my gut feeling for readability :)